# How to find a div using jquery when it is appended using d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am currently working in JavaScript jquery and d3.js library.
I am stuck in a problem and need help from experts

here is my code

```
<div id="d1", style="height: 200px; width: 540px" ></div>>
```

Now I have written a code using d3.js

```
 var p_div = "d1"
 div =  d3.select('#' + p_div).append('div')
                              .attr('id' , 'child' + p_div)
                              .attr('width', 340)
                              .attr('height', 200px)
                              .attr('style', 'float: left;');
```

My problem starts here I want the left and top position of my inner div using jquery so I wrote following lines of code

```
var par_div = "d1";
alert ($('#child' + par_div).position().left);
```

But I am getting an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null

I think the problem is because I have made the div using d3.js.Can any one please guide me how to find the left position of my child div

Thanks

Comment: **position().left** instead of **position().Left**

Comment: Yes I have used left it a typo error here.It not working

Comment: In that case, you should check, if jQuery "sees" the specified object:

`console.log($('#child' + par_div));`

Comment: @Glibnes jQuery does not sees the specified object

Comment: could you make a testcase on JSFiddle or some other host?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo:

```
$('#child' + par_div)
```

Should be:

```
$('#' + par_div)
```